# Check_mk event triggered

Tags: nagios, check-mk

I am using checK_mk 1.2.6p12 version I want to trigger an event on arrival of certain messages of crictical state.
But I am unable to find where to put my shell script so that it performs actions if something goes down.

please help me out am stuck on it.In my Global Settings no error console options is showing.

Comment: Custom scripts are generally put into the check_mk_agent/plugins sub directory.

Comment: Thanxs for reply @JimBlack but how can i perform action in check_mk can you please help me out i am stuck on it since 1 week.

Comment: Check_MK will perform the actions itself.  If a CRITICAL condition is detected by Check_MK, it will send a 'passive' alert into the Nagios system.  All alerts from Check_MK are sent passively to Nagios, via the Nagios External Command File.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 1.2 is the same, maybe it helps for 1.4 version or you already solved it.

- Go to Event Console, click in Settings.
- Create an Action, and choose in the "Type of Action" choose "Execute via Shell Script" and write your own script.
- Create a Rule Pack.
- Create a Rule with "Match syslog priority" option to CRITICAL.
- Send an event and see if it trigger your Action.